# How to update a Sender EmailAddress

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am sending email on behalf of a Shared MailBox - generic system account?

How do I update the sender in Outlook mail?

I am getting a Run-Time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method .From = "MYACCOUNT@ACCOUNT.com"

```vb
Function CreateEmail(MySQL As String)
'On Error GoTo Exit_Function:
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem 'rs As Recordset

Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MySQL)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
    If IsNull(rs!standard_e_mail_addr) Then
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
            Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
        End If
        Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With oEmailItem
            .To = rs!standard_e_mail_addr
            .From = "MYACCOUNT@ACCOUNT.com" ' **
            .Subject = "Mandatory Action Required Submit In-Person Identification Form for " & rs!emp_fname
            .Body = "EmpNo: " & rs!emp_no & vbCr & _
                    "EmpName: " & rs!emp_fname & vbCr & _
                    "DO NOT REPLY."

            .Display
            .Send
             rs.Edit
             rs!EmailNotification_Send = Date
             rs.Update

        End With
        Set oEmailItem = Nothing
        Set oOutlook = Nothing
        rs.MoveNext
End If
Loop

Else
End If
rs.Close
Exit Function:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: You need to add some narrative to your post and fix the code formatting. I tried and it won't let me. But really, what is the issue? Put whatever email address you want in place of "MYACCOUNT@ACCOUNT.com".

Comment: I am getting a Run-Time error '438':  Object doesn't support this property or method   .From = "MYACCOUNT@ACCOUNT.com"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427302/vba-code-to-send-email-from-secondary-email-address-in-outlook, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322540/change-the-from-field,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432256/sentonbehalfof-not-working-in-excel-2010-vba-code. If you find an answer in any of these, consider deleting your question as the site strives for one question without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try:   `.SentOnBehalfOfName = """SenderName"" <MyAccount@Address.com>"`

Also review: [Use another account for sender](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm)

Comment: Your link is broken. Try to provide the answer and reference to the page/forum/question that you've used or reviewed.

Comment: Sorry, Copy/Paste screwup. Fixed link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to call `Display` before calling the `Send` method.

If you have the shared mailbox configured in Outlook you need to use the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property which allows to set an `Account` object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. For example:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
  For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts  
    If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then  
      Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
      Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
      oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account"  
      oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
      oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
      oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
      oMail.Send  
    End If  
  Next  
End Sub
```

Use [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862145(v=office.15).aspx) as long as your Exchange account has SendAs permission for the shared mailbox or distribution group, it will be sent from the shared account or group, not sent on behalf of.

```
    With oEmailItem
        .To = rs!standard_e_mail_addr
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "MYACCOUNT@ACCOUNT.com" 
        .Subject = "Mandatory Action Required Submit In-Person Identification Form for " & rs!emp_fname
        .Body = "EmpNo: " & rs!emp_no & vbCr & _
                "EmpName: " & rs!emp_fname & vbCr & _
                "DO NOT REPLY."
        .Send
```